# CCAvenue Payment Module Giving Error in the Order Cart Page, Prestashop 1.6.1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, payment, prestashop-1.6

The CC Avenue module is giving the following error on the Order cart page, though the module as such is working and there is nothing wrong in it, but how do I remove this error?

Notice: Undefined index: ccavenue_error_message in /home/desigssq/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 38

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/desigssq/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 38 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the variable `$ccavenue_error_message` is in one of the `.tpl` files of the module, but is not defined in the `.php` file that calls it.

In the `.tpl` file, add a condition to the part of the code containing `$ccavenue_error_message`.
For example if you have:

```
<div class="error">{$ccavenue_error_message.text}</div>
```

replace it by:

```
{if isset($ccavenue_error_message)}<div class="error">{$ccavenue_error_message.text}</div>{/if}
```

Feel free to add the code of your tpl file so I can give you exactly the part to modify.

You should also ask the developer of the module to correct this bug.